# Argc and Optind are completely random

Tags: c, debugging

So as the title says in my C Program i get as command line inputs as usual argc and argv. However upon further inspecting, i realized that my incoming argc is a completely random number.

Here is the start of my program where i want to know the value of argc.

```
void debug(char *format, ...) {
    if(DEBUG_MODE!=0) return;
    va_list arg;

    va_start (arg, format);
    (void) fprintf (stdout, format, arg);
    va_end (arg);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    debug("ARGC %i\n", argc);
```

Where debug() is just a better print method. So when i start my program with:

```
./server
```

I just get as a result:

```
 ARGC -1786798448
```

So i really dont understand this.

Answer (score 1):

A variable of type `va_list` isn't something you can pass to `fprintf()`.

Try: `(void) vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);`

See [vprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/vfprintf)

Comment: Added a link for you as I was going to post the same answer

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! You helped me a lot here. I dont know i tried searching for this problem but didnt find it. Thanks again!